# Multiple Indexes search in Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have multiple lucene.net indexes that I would need to search on for a query string. So will I need to open a new IndexSearcher on all these indexes or can I achieve this with a single IndexSearcher?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be accomplished using the [MultiSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_4/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiSearcher.html).

It implements the Searchable interface over multiple subsearchers. If you only need methods from the Searchable interface it will be just like a regular IndexSearcher to you.

If you need to access the underlying searchers that found a document, you can use the `subSearcher(int)` and `subDoc(int)` methods.

http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_4/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiSearcher.html

Comment: MultiSearcher is deprecated since v3.5. Use [MultiReader](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiReader.html) instead.