# How to search Multiple Sites using Lucene Search engine API?

Tags: lucene.net

Hope that someone can help me as soon as possible :-)
I would like to know how can we search Multiple Sites using Lucene??! (All sites are in one index).

I have succeeded to search one website, and to index multiple sites, however I am not able to search all websites.

Consider this method that I have:

```
  private void PerformSearch()
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        //Create the Searcher object
        string strIndexDir = Server.MapPath("index") + @"\" + mstrURL;
        IndexSearcher objSearcher = new IndexSearcher(strIndexDir); 

        //Parse the query, "text" is the default field to search
        Query objQuery = QueryParser.Parse(mstrQuery, "text", new StandardAnalyzer()); 

        //Create the result DataTable
        mobjDTResults.Columns.Add("title", typeof(string));
        mobjDTResults.Columns.Add("path", typeof(string));
        mobjDTResults.Columns.Add("score", typeof(string));
        mobjDTResults.Columns.Add("sample", typeof(string));
        mobjDTResults.Columns.Add("explain", typeof(string));

        //Perform search and get hit count
        Hits objHits = objSearcher.Search(objQuery);
        mintTotal = objHits.Length();

        //Create Highlighter
        QueryHighlightExtractor highlighter = new QueryHighlightExtractor(objQuery, new StandardAnalyzer(), "<B>", "</B>");

        //Initialize "Start At" variable
        mintStartAt = GetStartAt();

        //How many items we should show?
        int intResultsCt = GetSmallerOf(mintTotal, mintMaxResults + mintStartAt);

        //Loop through results and display
        for (int intCt = mintStartAt; intCt < intResultsCt; intCt++) 
        {
            //Get the document from resuls index
            Document doc = objHits.Doc(intCt);

            //Get the document's ID and set the cache location
            string strID = doc.Get("id");
            string strLocation = "";
            if (mstrURL.Substring(0,3) == "www")
                strLocation = Server.MapPath("cache") + 
                    @"\" + mstrURL + @"\" + strID + ".htm";
            else
                strLocation = doc.Get("path") + doc.Get("filename");

            //Load the HTML page from cache
            string strPlainText;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strLocation, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                strPlainText = ParseHTML(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }

            //Add result to results datagrid
            DataRow row = mobjDTResults.NewRow();
            if (mstrURL.Substring(0,3) == "www")
                row["title"] = doc.Get("title");
            else
                row["title"] = doc.Get("filename");
            row["path"] = doc.Get("path");
            row["score"] = String.Format("{0:f}", (objHits.Score(intCt) * 100)) + "%";
            row["sample"] = highlighter.GetBestFragments(strPlainText, 200, 2, "...");
            Explanation objExplain = objSearcher.Explain(objQuery, intCt);
            row["explain"] = objExplain.ToHtml();
            mobjDTResults.Rows.Add(row);
        } 
        objSearcher.Close();

        //Finalize results information
        mTsDuration = DateTime.Now - start;
        mintFromItem = mintStartAt + 1;
        mintToItem = GetSmallerOf(mintStartAt + mintMaxResults, mintTotal);
    }
```

As you can see that I use the site URL `mstrURL` when I create the search object

```
string strIndexDir = Server.MapPath("index") + @"\" + mstrURL;
```

How can I do the same when I want to search multiple sites??

Actually I am  using [this](http://www.keylimetie.com/blog/2005/8/4/lucenenet/) code.

Answer (score 0):

Combine each of your site's `Searcher` within a `MultiSearcher`

See this question for more details:
[Multiple Indexes search in Lucene.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677845/multiple-indexes-search-in-lucene-net/7677977#7677977)